# Send email with attachment using openssl s_client in bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, openssl

How to send an email with attachment using openssl s_client command as:

```
openssl s_client -crlf -quiet -starttls smtp -connect $SMTPHostName:587
```

using bash script

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe smtp commands into the openssl s_client with

```
$ openssl s_client -crlf -quiet -starttls smtp -connect smtp.xs4all.nl:587 <<< QUIT
```

Result:

```
depth=2 C = US, ST = New Jersey, L = Jersey City, O = The USERTRUST Network, CN = USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = smtp.xs4all.nl
verify return:1
250 8BITMIME
221 2.0.0 Bye
```

Available commands can be shown with 'help'.
The sequence of commands is usually something like this:

```
helo mail.example.com
data
To: dummy@dummy.nl
From: dummy@example.com
Date: Fri, 15 dec 2021 14:00:00 -0200
Message-ID: <xxxx.xxxx.xx@mail.example.com>

This is a test
.
```

NB. There may be an authentication needed.

To add an attachment something like the following needs to be added to the email.

```
Content-Type: image/png;
              name="bullet.png"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: x-uuencode

begin 664 bullet.png
MB5!...
<snipped>
'
end
```

The file bullet.png was encoded with uuencode to ascii and added to the message. You can use other MIME formats.

Commands can vary from mailserver to mailserver depending on what for mailextensions and RFC's they support

Comment: And why does this feel like a "red team" question? :-)

Comment: Data extraction, "living off the land" and all that.